# Xlwings - Issue with running on 64-bit python?

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, pywin32, xlwings

I am able to use xlwings at home with no issues on two different machines, but I am having significant issues running xlwings on my work computer.

Our company does have Anaconda as an approved program, but I keep getting the `"No module named 'win32api'"` error.  My company computer is running Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit), Python 3.4.1 (64-bit), and `xlwings 0.7.1.`

When my IS person saw that error, I informed him we needed to run `pywin32`, but he said that pywin32 was 32-bit Python, which (he said) was inconsistent with 64-bit python.

Note: my computer does have both `xlwings32.dll` and `xlwings64.dll`.

Does anyone know if the xlwings program runs only 32-bit python, or am I missing something in the installation.  Keep in mind that I do not have admin privileges, so I can't just "install an updated version".

Comment: I think you mean your IT person rather than your IS person, unless Islamic State really are doing your IT support in which case you have bigger problems. pywin32 runs just fine on 64 bit Windows.  The 32 is just a hangover from the days when the Windows API was known as Win32. It wouldn't be much fun if the package used a different name on 64 bit Windows would it. Your IT person doesn't know what he/she is talking about.

Comment: fwiw, xlwings runs fine on my 64 bit machine, so that's unlikely to be your problem.